# UI Grid doesn't immediately update after changing grid options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

I'm working on an AngularJS project using the [UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/) module.  I would like to have row filtering available as an option, but not a lot of users need it and the filter boxes take up a lot of space so I want to start with the filtering option disabled and have a button to enable it as needed.  So I set `enableFiltering: false` and added in a button that runs `$scope.gridOptions.enableFiltering = !$scope.gridOptions.enableFiltering;`, but clicking it didn't seem to do anything.  After some more testing, I found that if I started with `enableFiltering: true`, clicking the button still wouldn't do anything immediately, but if I clicked it and then tried to type in one of the filter boxes, they would disappear as soon as I started typing (but still would not reappear even if I clicked the button again).

Any idea for how I can get this working properly?  I already tried $scope.$apply(), but that only gave me "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress."  Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/L5bgA4XukmYJaVQHVkgR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want I guess: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qyts0zQrltx4QxlOWgob?p=preview

Inspired by this example from ui-grip website: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/103_filtering

```
angular.module('app',['ui.grid']).controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', 'uiGridConstants', function($scope, uiGridConstants){
  $scope.toggle = function(){
    $scope.gridOptions.enableFiltering = !$scope.gridOptions.enableFiltering;
    $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange( uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN );
  }
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: [{name:'Bob',age:20},{name:'Joe',age:21}],
    enableFiltering: true,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    },
  }
}]);
```

1. Injected uiGridConstant
2. Added gridApi for notifying data change to ui-grid
3. Using gridApi on click of data toggle

Comment: Thanks!  The notifyDataChange was all I was missing, added that in and now it's working perfectly.